# Automate Generate Dates in Jupyter Notebook Markdown

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I want to have an "updated date" in my Jupyter Notebook markdown. Can someone tells me if I could have that date populated automatically? If so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I figured that I could just run the cell as the alternative... it works!

Comment: print('Last Updated On: ', datetime.datetime.now())

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`IPython.display`](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#module-IPython.display)  module in combination with [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

```py
from datetime import datetime
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

todays_date = str(datetime.now().date())

display(Markdown(f'# Report for Week {todays_date}'))
```

Answer adapted from answers to the question: [How to programmatically generate markdown output in Jupyter notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/how-to-programmatically-generate-markdown-output-in-jupyter-notebooks)