# Keep IPython markdown in jupyter notebook after closing it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

In jupyter notebook, I am calling a function of a library that does `IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Markdown(...))` (see [How to programmatically generate markdown output in Jupyter notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/how-to-programmatically-generate-markdown-output-in-jupyter-notebooks)). It successfully displays the desired Markdown.

However, if I close the notebook tab, and open it again, the output is replaced with `<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>`.

Is there a way to avoid this automatic change, and keep the desired Markdown?

Comment: Have you tried setting the notebook to trusted?

Comment: I confirm that trusting the notebook fixes the issue.