# How to print format exponent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to know if there is any way I can print x^2 in string format like we do in mathematics like x2. where 2 is in exponential form in top right corner of x.

[image: Example]

Comment: You can take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028267/print-latex-formula-with-python

Comment: Do you need something general (any n^m) or just for two? If just the latter, you could use https://unicode-table.com/en/00B2/

Comment: Python strings can contain Unicode characters, so `print('x²')` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def stringify_exponent(n, m):
    superscripted = "".join(_DIGITS[int(d)] for d in str(m))
    return f"{n}{superscripted}"


_DIGITS = [
    "\N{superscript zero}",
    "\N{superscript one}",
    "\N{superscript two}",
    "\N{superscript three}",
    "\N{superscript four}",
    "\N{superscript five}",
    "\N{superscript six}",
    "\N{superscript seven}",
    "\N{superscript eight}",
    "\N{superscript nine}"
]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(stringify_exponent(10, 2))
    print(stringify_exponent(2, 1024))
```

Printing:

```
10²
2¹⁰²⁴
```