# How to use math sympy symbols in aiogram?

Tags: python, sympy, aiogram, text-rendering

How can I use sympy’s symbols in my `aiogram` telegram bot’s answers like Jupiter notebook does?

For example this code:

```
from sympy import Symbol, Eq, sqrt

h = Symbol('h')
a = Symbol('a')

AB = sqrt(h**2 + (a/2)**2)
AB
```

Is this possible?

Everything I tried doesn’t work.

Comment: I guess you mean you want to have rendered TEX-formulas, right? If so, maybe this here helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028267/how-to-render-latex-markup-using-python